# Adding days to unix timestamp in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I need to delete all entries in a table where the active column is false and that the expire date being 30 days back or more from current date. But how do I add the 30 days to the timestamp in where CLAUSE? I tried this but get a malformed SQL exception

```
DELETE * FROM share
         WHERE active = false
         AND (expire + 30) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

I could not get `timestampadd` to work either.

Comment: What is your expire column data type?

Comment: It is `timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DELETE FROM share
 WHERE active = false
 AND from_unixtime(expire) + interval 30 day > curr_date();
```

or since unix time is in seconds:

```
 DELETE FROM share
 WHERE active = false
 AND expire + (30*86400) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, to make sure that MySQL can actually use indexes, you should do something like this:

`DELETE FROM share WHERE active = false AND expire <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30 * 24 * 3600;`